# Combining rotations using makehgtform

Tags: matlab, rotation, transform

I've written a small Matlab program to simulate an airplane with orthogonal rate gyros. It is based on a Matlab example. The program allows initial conditions to be set for airplane roll, pitch and yaw, and arrays of rate gyro data are created. The Matlab function makehgtform() is used in a loop to update the orientation of the airplane, using the rate-gyro data. The axes of the 3d plot are the global axes and the rate gyros are aligned with the local axes of the airplane.

The problem is as follows: When I set a non-zero initial condition for roll, then non-zero rate-gyro data for pitch or yaw cause the airplane to pitch or yaw about its own axes, as it should. When the initial condition for yaw is non-zero, and pitch or roll data is applied through the rate-gyros, the airplane pitches or rolls about the global axes rather than its own local axes. When the initial value of pitch is non-zero, then rate-gyro yaw data works correctly, but roll data causes the airplane to roll about the global rather than local axes.

The easiest way to see the problem is to make only one initial condition non-zero and apply rate gyro data on either of the other two axes; for example set pitch = 0.5 and Gyro_yaw = ones(nSamples, 1) * 0.2; with Gyro_roll and Gyro_pitch zeroed out.

I have previously tried using a separate makehgtform() call for each axis and then concatenate the results, but this raises the problem of matrix multiplication not being commutative, so there is no 'correct order' for multiplication of the transforms. The use of the combined version of makehgtform(), as seen in my code, behaves exactly is if the transforms were performed individually and multiplied in the order x_rotate * y_rotate * z_rotate, which of course is not correct.

```
clf

% set the limits and select a view
ax = axes('Xlim', [-2 2], 'YLim', [-2 2], 'ZLim', [-1.5 1.5]);
view(3);
grid on;
axis equal

% Set up vehicle model
[xc yc zc] = cylinder([0.1 0.0]); % cone
[x y z] = cylinder([0.2 0.2]);

h(1) = surface(x, z,  - 0.5 * y,  'FaceColor', 'blue');   % left wing
h(2) = surface(zc, yc, xc, 'FaceColor', 'red');    % nose
h(3) = surface(-1.5 * z, y,  0.5 * x, 'FaceColor', 'red');    % fuselage
h(4) = surface(x, -z, 0.5 * y, 'FaceColor', 'yellow'); % right wing
h(5) = surface((1.5 * xc) - 1.3, yc, z, 'FaceColor', 'red');    % tail

% Create group object and parent surfaces
t = hgtransform('Parent', ax);
set(h, 'Parent', t);

% Set the renderer to OpenGL and update the display
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'opengl');
drawnow

% Initial conditions in radians
roll = 0;
pitch = 0.5;
yaw = 0;

nSamples = 40;

% Set up rate gyro data. Activate individual rate gyro by using ones() 
% and deactivate by using zeros(), in which case, the scaling is 
% irrelevant
Gyro_roll = zeros(nSamples, 1) * 0.2;  % roll
Gyro_pitch = zeros(nSamples, 1) * 0.2; % pitch
Gyro_yaw = ones(nSamples, 1) * 0.2;    % yaw

for i = 1 : numel(Gyro_roll)

    rotation = makehgtform('xrotate', roll, 'yrotate', pitch, 'zrotate', yaw);
    set(t, 'Matrix', rotation);

    % Update orientation
    roll = roll + Gyro_roll(i);
    pitch = pitch + Gyro_pitch(i);
    yaw = yaw + Gyro_yaw(i);

    pause

end
```